# aws ec2 windows machine - couldnot RDP

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a ec2 windows machine, suddenly since past 2 days I am not able to RDP it, the machine and the apps are running though.

The RDP port was already open in this security group, and I was able to log in to other machines using the same security group, but still not on this very machine.

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

In the AWS console you need to open the port for RDP in the EC2 > Security Groups section.

By default, the RDP server listens on TCP port 3389 and UDP port 3389.

***Or try turning it off and on again.***

If you have already done this and it has recently stopped working, you could try rebooting the instance in the AWS console to see if that gets things working again.

You could also check if you are trying to connect to the right IP or AWS DNS address, if you have failed to use an elastic IP address.

Comment: The RDP port was already open in this security group, and I was being able to log in to other machines using the same security group, but still not on this very machine.